# Html/Css Jssor Slider not working in chrome only but no errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am currently having problems getting the Jssor Slider working in chrome.
It used to work until a certain update.
I am not aware of what update exactly.

It does work on IE properly, and in chrome it loads and has functionality, but shows no images. I cannot find any errors in the console.

Url: http://www.taalinblokjes.nl/alle-materialen/?productId=4#c10

Does anyone know what is causing it to show no images anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Update JSSOR to the newest version here:
http://www.jssor.com/download-jssor-slider-development-kit.html

and then add:$HWA:false to the options

Example:

```
  <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = {
                $DragOrientation: 3,  
                $FillMode: 1,                               //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $HWA:false                                       
                }
            };

            //var sliders = new Object();

            $('.jssorSliderItem').each(function() {
                var id = this.id;
                var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(id, options);
               // sliders[id] = jssor_slider1;    
            });

        });
    </script>
```